# where is my Admin UI in kubernetes deployed using kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I created a kubernetes cluster on aws using kops. Really incredible work done by the kops guys.
I was able to validate it successfully using "kops validate cluster".

1. Now is there any UI console or dashboard I can access?
2. Incidentally when I tried accessing the aws loadbalancer over https using the public dns I got a prompt for username and password. what is the username and password to feed here? Or is this something to ignore?

Thanks.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a admin dashboard provided by k8s community. Take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

Assuming you are in the right context, you can create dashboard through terminal by running the following command

`kubectl create -f https://git.io/kube-dashboard`

You will find your username & password in kube config file. To view that file run this command
`kubectl config view`